# using d3.selectAll with react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

I want to be able to replicate this demo: https://bl.ocks.org/danasilver/cc5f33a5ba9f90be77d96897768802ca but instead of standard svg circles I would like to use React components. From all the research I have done the standard fare was usually to wrap d3 code in a React component instead of the other way around. I want to be able to, instead of writing this code:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(points)
  .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('r', r)
    .call(drag);
```

I would like to write code like this:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll({{insert react component here}})
    .data({{pass in the props here (or elsewhere)}})
  .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('r', r)
    .call(drag);
```

Essentially I would like to use react components instead of standard svg elements. Please let me know if this is possible to do or if a better solution exists.

I did attempt something like this (it scrolls by the way):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import { scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale’
import { max } from 'd3-array'
import { select } from 'd3-selection'

const testcomponent = ({children, ...props}) => {
    <span> hello </span>
}

class DragArea extends Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.createDragArea = this.createDragArea.bind(this)
   }
   componentDidMount() {
      this.createDragArea()
   }
   componentDidUpdate() {
      this.createDragArea()
   }
   createDragArea() {
      const node = this.node
      var width = 960,
      height = 500,
      resolution = 20,
      r = 15;

      var points = d3.range(10).map(function() {
          return {
              x: round(Math.random() * width, resolution),
              y: round(Math.random() * height, resolution)
          };
      });

      var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
          .origin(function(d) { return d; })
          .on('drag', dragged);

      var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
          .attr('width', width)
          .attr('height', height);

      svg.selectAll('.vertical')
          .data(d3.range(1, width / resolution))
      .enter().append('line')
          .attr('class', 'vertical')
          .attr('x1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
          .attr('y1', 0)
          .attr('x2', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
          .attr('y2', height);

      svg.selectAll('.horizontal')
          .data(d3.range(1, height / resolution))
      .enter().append('line')
          .attr('class', 'horizontal')
          .attr('x1', 0)
          .attr('y1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
          .attr('x2', width)
          .attr('y2', function(d) { return d * resolution; });

       var circles = svg.selectAll('testcomponent')
           .data(points)
       .enter().append('circle')
           .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
           .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
           .attr('r', r)
           .call(drag);

    function dragged(d) {
        var x = d3.event.x,
            y = d3.event.y,
            gridX = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(width - r, resolution),
            gridY = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(height - r, resolution);

        d3.select(this).attr('cx', d.x = gridX).attr('cy', d.gridY);
    }

    function round(p, n) {
        return p % n < n / 2 ? p - (p % n) : p + n - (p % n);
    }
}
render() {
      return <svg ref={node => this.node = node}
      width={500} height={500}>
          <testcomponent></testcomponent>
      </svg>
   }
}
export default DragArea
```

but it definitely doesn't work. I don't think it recognizes the selector or something of the sort.

Comment: It's probably worth at least including what you've tried and what problems you've encountered, otherwise this question is likely to get closed. I'd suggest you go edit it to give some examples of how far you've got so far with different approaches.

Comment: That is true, I'll add those in now.

Comment: At a glance, you might be able to use refs to get the dom node for the react component. Alternatively, you can apply a `className` to the component and then use that class name in the `selectAll` function.